# SLF4J Linkage Error

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, slf4j, websphere-8

I have configured JMS Provide in WebSphere Application Server that will use ActiveMQ. For sending message WebSphere needs "`activemq-all-5.9.1.jar`" in classpath so I added it. This "`activemq-all`" contains `slf4j classes` in it.

Now my application contains "`slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar`". When I start WebSphere it gives

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:264)
```

I tried using different activemq jars that does not contain slf4j classes but at that time it gives `ClassNotFoundExeption`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042322/websphere-classloader-gives-java-lang-linkageerror-when-loading-slf4j-loggerfact

Comment: There is no version issue as I also tried placing same version jar in server and application.

Comment: Can you add WebSphere AS version?

Comment: WebSphere AS version = 8.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because slf4j logger cannot be binded twice. In current scenario both server and application are binding slf4j logger.

Use old ActiveMQ jars that does not depend on slf4j logger. In this way applications default logger will work.